# Applescript to mount network drives no longer working on 10.8.4

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set VPNservice to service "Company VPN" -- name of the VPN service
        set isConnected to connected of current configuration of VPNservice
        if isConnected then
            -- the user_name field will show as blank
        set user_name to ""
        repeat while user_name = ""
            set user_name to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter your user name:" default answer user_name)
        end repeat
        -- the pass_word field will show as blank
        set pass_word to ""
        repeat while pass_word = ""
            set pass_word to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter your password:" default answer pass_word with hidden answer)
        end repeat
        --Mount network drives using entered credentials
            try
                    mount volume "smb://user_name:pass_word@server/share"
                mount volume "smb://user_name:pass_word@server/share"
            end try
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

I get a syntax error: Expected end of line but found property. Location is highlighted on the second line. Why would this no longer work?

Answer (score 2):

System Events knows about network preferences, not the Finder. So change "Finder" to "System Events" in your first line.

In addition, the "mount volume" command is an applescript command... not a Finder or System Events command. As such it shouldn't be in any tell block of code.

So you have a couple issues. I'm actually surprised your code worked in prior versions of MacOS X because these are not new things to 10.8.4. Here's how I would write your code...

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set VPNservice to service "Company VPN" -- name of the VPN service
        set isConnected to connected of current configuration of VPNservice
    end tell
end tell

if isConnected then
    -- the user_name field will show as blank
    set user_name to ""
    repeat while user_name = ""
        set user_name to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter your user name:" default answer user_name)
    end repeat
    -- the pass_word field will show as blank
    set pass_word to ""
    repeat while pass_word = ""
        set pass_word to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter your password:" default answer pass_word with hidden answer)
    end repeat
    --Mount network drives using entered credentials
    try
        mount volume "smb://user_name:pass_word@server/share"
        mount volume "smb://user_name:pass_word@server/share"
    end try
end if
```

Comment: Perfect!

Works like a charm, Thank you Regulus!

Comment: Glad it works. Please put the check mark by this answer to let everyone know you found your answer. Good luck.